# Find nested data SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with promo sales, but some promos last a different amount of time.

```
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| year_id | week_number | good_id | store_id | promo_name | qty |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 41          | 22197   | 64       | October    | 10  |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 42          | 22197   | 64       | October    | 2   |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 43          | 22197   | 64       | October    | 54  |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 44          | 22197   | 64       | October    | 3   |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 41          | 22197   | 64       | Flash      | 13  |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 42          | 22197   | 64       | Flash      | 56  |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 42          | 22197   | 64       | New        | 41  |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 43          | 22197   | 64       | New        | 4   |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
```

I would like to find for each pair of good-store all such cases where shorter promos go into longer ones and change their name, for example:

```
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| year_id | week_number | good_id | store_id | promo_name | qty |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 41          | 22197   | 64       | October    | 10  |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 42          | 22197   | 64       | October    | 2   |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 43          | 22197   | 64       | October    | 54  |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 44          | 22197   | 64       | October    | 3   |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 41          | 22197   | 64       | October    | 13  |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 42          | 22197   | 64       | October    | 56  |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 42          | 22197   | 64       | October    | 41  |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
| 2019    | 43          | 22197   | 64       | October    | 4   |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+------------+-----+
```

Comment: How is this an example of "nested data"?

Comment: What does "where shorter promos go into longer ones" mean? What does "go into" mean in this context, exactly?

Comment: You really need to explain what your logic is here, and show us your attempts. Remember, you're talking to people that have no knowledge of the system you're using, or what your data means.

Comment: Means that the dates of the promotion (year and week) are included in the dates of the longer promotion, but do not exceed them and do not exactly coincide

Answer (score 1):

For the first value of promo_name when sorted by year & week for the same good_id & store_id

Then the [FIRST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql) window function would be my pick.

```
SELECT year_id, week_number, good_id, store_id, 
 FIRST_VALUE(promo_name) OVER (PARTITION BY good_id, store_id ORDER BY year_id, week_number) AS promo_name,
qty
FROM PromoSales ps
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

To use it in an update

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
     promo_name, 
     FIRST_VALUE(promo_name) OVER (PARTITION BY good_id, store_id ORDER BY year_id, week_number) AS original_promo_name
    FROM PromoSales
)
UPDATE CTE
SET promo_name = original_promo_name
WHERE promo_name != original_promo_name
  AND original_promo_name IS NOT NULL;
```